# Hashbang link previews and crawling in Facebook and others popular services

Tags: facebook, seo, web-crawler, hashbang

Do currently any popular websites support previewing links with hashbangs?

E.g. pasting link like

```
  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pigfi/cF6GzPfeuO8
```

To a Facebook chat message.

(Translates to https://groups.google.com/forum/?_escaped_fragment_=topic/pigfi/cF6GzPfeuO8 )

- There exists a spec for crawling hashbang URLs https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started
- However, I found little information which websites or popular services currently support crawling / previewing these kind of hash bang URLs (besides GoogleBot?)